# Seeding Rails with non-ASCII characters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows

I'm hesitant to ask this again, because there are so many questions here with variants of same title, but none of them solves my problem :(

When I run the `db:seed` rake task I get an error "Invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII (Argument Error)". Presumably that's because one of the tables contains non-ASCII characters. It's supposed to, and has to, so the solutions here that involve replacing non-ASCII characters with ASCII ones are no help to me.

From other answers here, I've tried adding:

```
# encoding: utf-8
```

or

```
# ruby encoding: utf-8
```

or

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

to the very top of my seeds file, but it makes no difference. I've also tried adding them to the top of `bin/rake` (after the shebang, in that case).

I've tried adding:

```
if RUBY_VERSION =~ /1.9/
  Encoding.default_external = Encoding::UTF_8
  Encoding.default_internal = Encoding::UTF_8
end
```

to the top of my gemfile.

None of that has made any difference. I've also tried uninstalling the `i18n` gem and reinstalling it, and that's made no difference either.

So how *do* I get rake to seed my file with non-ASCII data?

This is a Rails project under Windows 8.1, Ruby 1.9.3, with everything in its default place, by the way.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: Full backtrace:-

```
C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\bin\ruby.exe -e   $stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift) C:/Users/User/RubymineProjects/TrafficForecast/bin/rake --trace db:seed
** Invoke db:seed (first_time)
** Execute db:seed
** Invoke db:abort_if_pending_migrations (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute db:abort_if_pending_migrations
rake aborted!
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake- 10.3.1/lib/rake/trace_output.rb:16:in `block in trace_on': invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII (ArgumentError)
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.3.1/lib/rake/trace_output.rb:14:in `map'
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.3.1/lib/rake/trace_output.rb:14:in `trace_on'
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:372:in `trace'
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:218:in `display_exception_message_details'
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:205:in `display_exception_details'
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:198:in `display_error_message'
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:185:in `rescue in standard_exception_handling'
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
from C:/Users/User/RubymineProjects/TrafficForecast/bin/rake:5:in `<top (required)>'
from -e:1:in `load'
from -e:1:in `<main>'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: It could be helpful if a full backtrace is provided. (`rake db:seed --trace`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not try Ruby 2.0+ to do the rake task as it's default encoding is UTF-8 :) BTW, you can use [pik](https://github.com/vertiginous/pik) to switch your ruby version under windows.

---

I got the same error when testing under ruby 1.9.3 with rails 4.0.0. And it is working for me to add`# encoding: utf-8` to the first line of the related model file as I also have UTF-8 string in it. For example:

*seeds.rb*

```
# coding: utf-8
...
Project.create({:name=>"#{UTF8_char}"})
```

*model/project.rb*

```
# coding: utf-8
...
str = "#{another_UTF8_char}"
```

Just try it.

Comment: Because I'm trying to learn rails by following the tutorials in "Agile Web Development with Rails 4", and that warns that some of the examples might not work as expected in Ruby 2.0+.

Comment: Ok, I put it at the top of all model and controller files, and it seems to have done the trick. They didn't contain any non-ASCII characters, but I suppose they passed through.

Comment: Well, you can try magic_encoding to add that comment automatically to your .rb files.

Comment: I tried magic_encoding and can't get it to work -- I have another open question about that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23223696/using-magic-encoding-gem-under-windows